# Completely remove Windows Defender from my laptop?

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, uninstall

Unfortunately, it seems as if Windows Defender is causing severe problems with my Windows 7 x64 laptop. I would like to uninstall it completely - not just disable it, but get rid of it from my system. Windows Defender is like a parasite that slows my system down to a crawl.

The problem is that when the laptop starts, the Windows Defender service has doesn't start properly (perhaps due to ESET Antivirus). The computer slows down to about 3% of its usual speed until I manually restart the Windows Defender service. The net result of this is that it take my laptop 15 minutes to restart.

Comment: Try to disable Windows Defender service.

Comment: Sounds like you are more likely infected with something.  Have you tried a `sfc /scannow` to verify the intrigity of your system image?